What Statistical test to use on my project?
I am very confused about what kind of statistical test to use in RStudio on my project,
I have measured the mean salinity for 3 levels of population density (low medium and high) across 6 months (therefore 6 mean values per population density level)
I want to see if there is a statistical significance between the mean Salinity value (Quantitative continuous data) and Population Density (categorical; low, medium, high) but I'm not sure which test to use I have tried both Friedmans & Kruskal-wallis but not sure which to use.
Many Thanks for any advice!

For clarification, you have data for month 1, month 2, etc to month 6?   Are you interested in change over time or just if there is a difference between the population levels?

Hiya I have data for 6 monthes, but this was only to increase the size of my data set , i am more interested in the differnece between the population levels in order to accertain whether a preference in distribution is show to differnent salinity levels!

One more question - how many replicates do you have of each population density?  You say "I have measured the mean salinity for 3 levels of population density"   did you measure salinity in one place with low density and take the mean of the measurements for six months , or do you have the more than one place with low population density and take the mean at month one, months 2, etc. ?  ( also what is varying at the different populations?   A plant?)

hey thanks for the reply, so the data was extracted from qgis maps that I made, a kernal density heatmap was made of the distribution of sharks I'm looking at for a whole month, eg. january. I then split the heatmap into three sections containing low medium and high density, once split I extracted the mean salinity from the overlapping area of each density. so I have separate mean salinity values for low, medium and high. this was repeated for the other 5 months so I have 18 mean values into with 6 values in each density level. hope this is what you mean?

I also extracted the SD, range and count if this helps?

Interesting study.  Is this the same location each time, or a different locations depending on where the sharks were? (Are these GPS tagged aninals?)   Standard statistical inference requires independent samples , so ideally you'd have something like 3 unique places where sharks live, like 3 different bays, then in each location you'd determine population density and could take the mean salinity and mean density across the 3 sites eg mean for density low with n = 3 sites, mean for density medium for n = 3 sites, etc

each month of the study the sharks where is slightly different areas of the gulf but due to being highly mobile these where very large areas, but the hotspot locations where never identical so differed each month.
